# For loop in recursive function continues after end of recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, graph

I am implementing a Depth First Search on a graph in C++. Given a starting vertex, the algorithm should perform DFS until a goal node is found (i.e. a node with `goal` set to true), and return the path taken.  I am trying to do this recursively, here is my code:

```c++
vector<char>* dfs(graph g, node* s){

    static vector<char> path;
    s->set_visited();
    path.push_back(s->get_tag()); //Adds node to path

    if(s->is_goal()){
        g.set_all_visited();
    }

    else{
        for(int i=0; i<(s->get_no_edges()); i++){
            if(!(s->get_edge(i)->get_dest()->is_visited())) //If it is unvisited, apply recursion
                dfs(g, s->get_edge(i)->get_dest());
        }
    }

    return &path;
}
```

I am aware that the resulting path will just list the nodes in the order they were visited by the DFS, as opposed to an actual path from the start to a goal node.

The problem is that the function continues to print nodes even after a goal node is found. To avoid this, I set all nodes in the graph `g` to visited using `set_all_visited()`, and checked in the `else` part whether a node was visited or not before proceeding, but this does not seem to be working. When I performed dry runs, the function kept on visiting all the edges of a node in the `for` loop even after a goal node was found, and I do not know how I can stop this from happening.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with passing `g` by value. Try passing it by reference. The `g` in which you mark all nodes as visited is not the same `g` available to the other recursive calls.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Specifically in this case, you seem sure that it's staying in a for loop -- therefore `i<(s->get_no_edges())` is true. So look at `i` and `s->get_no_edges()` in a debugger (or use `cout`, the poor-man's-debugger), and see for yourself why the condition remains true.

Comment: @IVlad I tried it and it seems to be working now! Such a silly mistake. Thanks!

Comment: I don't know your implementation of `graph` but are you sure you want to pass it by value and not by reference to `dfs`? Maybe you create a copy of your graph every time you invoke it? But in general, for a DFS implementation there are **many** issues in your code.

Comment: @AlexanderStante Specifically?

Comment: I'm referring to your design. What happens with `path` if you want to execute a DFS on an other graph? You mark the fact that a node was visited directly on a node. You add every visited note to `path`. You stop your recursion by marking all nodes as "visited". Recursion is also questionable of DFS if you can't do tail call optimization. I know it's a toy example, but there is so much computer science literature about proper DFS and Graph Implementations.

Comment: @AlexanderStante For my particular assignment, I don't have to run it on another graph. Rather, I need to run many search algorithms on the same graph. As for every visited node being added to path, I am fixing that now but first wanted to make sure that this was working. What would you suggest doing instead of marking all nodes as visited to stop recursion? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `g` by value instead of by reference. This means that whenever you found a goal node and are coming back from a recursive call, that instance of `g` still has its nodes set as unvisited. That's why the repetition occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I know your primary question is answered, still I would give few suggestions:

1) Don't use static vector, you can't reuse the function. You can instead create a vector where you're expecting the path and pass pointer to the vector.

2) To make sure you don't have all visited nodes in path, you can return a bool from dfs function to denote if there is a path to destination. You can also avoid passing graph object this way.

With those changes your code will become:

```
bool dfs(node* s, vector<char>* path){

    s->set_visited();

    if(s->is_goal()){
        path.push_back(s->get_tag());
        return true;
    }

    else{
        for(int i=0; i<(s->get_no_edges()); i++){
            if(!(s->get_edge(i)->get_dest()->is_visited())) //If it is unvisited, apply recursion
                if(dfs(s->get_edge(i)->get_dest(), path)) {
                    path.push_back(s->get_tag());
                    return true;
                }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This will return reverse path, ie path from destination to source, there is std::reverse.

If you do a BFS, you'll get shortest path instead of some random path, assuming the edges are of equal weight.